# TTStyledTextLabel loading a web image inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20

I have TTStyledTextLabel inside a UITableViewCell. The label loads a HTML string with references to web image resources. The problem I am facing is that once the image has been loaded the dimensions of the label need to be changed and hence the UITableViewCell.

Any idea as to how this should be done.

Would appreciate any help. This has consumed a lot of my time.

Comment: you should accept more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

I scanned for all the text to see what images have to be downloaded. Once the images have been identified, i initiated their download using TTURLRequest. After the images were downloaded the sizeThatFits api returns the correct height.

This way is a bit slow, but solves the problem, until I am able to figure out a better way.